# How to use visudo command isndie openshift pod

Tags: ubuntu, openshift, redhat, openshift-4

I need to run visudo -c -f command from openshift pod terminal but when I run the command it says **visudo command not found** anyone here knows how to run those command without any issues. Do I need to install or configure any specific package with in the cluster?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I think in openshift you do not have access directly to the platform. You might need to change is using RBAC

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The pod is running what image?
Obviously "visudo" is not par of the binary image you are using...
Try to start a pod with an image where visudo is installed
Nothing to do with OpenShift

Comment: hi @titou10  I am running spring boot app which uses oracle-jdk-rhel8 image and I need to run those command via code but as you said base image itself is not having sudo, is there any way we can check from repository whether particular image supports sudo or not?

Comment: Build your own image, based on "oracle-jdk-rhel8" and install sudo and all the tools you need (in Dockerfile FROM oracle-jdk-rhel8  then "yum install sudo"... ) or choose another base image with the JDK that already has sudo installed

Comment: I tried this 

FROM <repo-url>/oracle-jdk-rhel8/17e64:latest
EXPOSE 8080
COPY /target/app.jar /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN yum install sudo
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/app.jar" ]

but got below error in openshift tekton logs which building image :-

No match for argument: sudo
Error: Unable to find a match: sudo
subprocess exited with status 1
subprocess exited with status 1